# Can't select option with specific value in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I can't select an option in a select box with a specific value. This is the code I am using:

```
$('#group_e option[value="'+parameters.group+'"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

I did `console.log()` the `parameters.group` value so I know it is equal to the option I am trying to select.

I am doing this in an XCODE emulator using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically change a select box selection from within the control's own change event and have it work in mobile browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252664/how-can-i-programmatically-change-a-select-box-selection-from-within-the-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the select to reflect the changes after changing value:

```
 $('#group_e').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: 1) you can't call `.selectmenu()` on an `option`, it should be called on `select` itself. 2) `.selectmenu("refresh")` is enough.

Comment: @Omar: not sure why it worked for OP but i was under the impression that i have used select selector and not option. Thanks for update.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that either but it does work on the option itself somehow. But I will correct it ofcourse since you never know what trouble it might give later, thanks!